# Proper typing for class function decorator

Tags: python, mypy, pyright

What would be the proper way to type the `print_before` function decorator, so that the
wrapped function has the proper type but I can't use the decorator on a class that would not work?

thank you

```py
def print_before(func):
    def func_wrapper(self, *args):
        self.print_hi()
        return func(self, *args)
    return func_wrapper


class PrintThings:
    def print_hi(self):
        print("hi")

    @print_before
    def add_nums(self, a: int, b: int) -> int:
        return a + b


pt = PrintThings()
pt.add_nums(5, 4)


class ShouldNotWork:
    @print_before
    def add_nums(self, a: int, b: int) -> int:
        return a + b


snw = ShouldNotWork()
snw.add_nums(4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

The decorator has a very general type as written. The only thing you know about the wrapper is that it accepts at least one argument of some unknown type, and returns some unknown type. As for the decorator itself, you only know that it returns something with the same type as its argument.

Actually, there is one more thing we know. Whatever the type of `self` is, it must have a `print_hi` method. We can represent that using a `Protocol`.

We also introduce a type variable `T`, which represents the *same* class (or a subclass thereof) each time it is used in the signature of `print_before`.

```
from typing import Any, Tuple, Protocol, TypeVar

class PrintsHi(Protocol):
    def print_hi(self):
        pass


T = TypeVar('T', bound=PrintsHi)


def print_before(func: Callable[[T, Tuple[Any,...]], Any]) -> Callable[[T, Tuple[Any,...]], Any]:
    def func_wrapper(self: T, *args: Tuple[Any,...]):
        self.print_hi()
        return func(self, *args)
    return func_wrapper
```

Comment: but I also know that self cannot be `Any`, since it needs to have a function `print_hi` defined

Comment: Fixed that, but it's still not quite right: we can also assume that the return value involves the same class (though possibly a subclass) used by the argument.

Comment: I _think_ it's fixed now, but I can't test it just now.

Comment: thank you for your help!

the newest iteration disallows both usages now :D

Argument of type "(self: PrintThings, a: int, b: int) -> int" cannot be assigned to parameter "func" of type "(p0: T, p1: Tuple[Any, ...]) -> Any" in function "print_before"
    ...
        "Tuple[Any, ...]" is incompatible with "int"
        Function accepts too few positional parameters; expected 3 but received 2

Comment: from what I understand I believe this is needed to solve my problem: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/
and it will only come with python 3.10 in a year